# How to cycle a class through siblings on an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a full screen carousel, I want the captions to be images, I couldn't find an appropriate plugin. So I am building a custom solution.

I figured out how to trigger an event during slide change. Now I want the visible class to cycle through divs with `.caption` under `div.carousel-captions`

```
<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg" data-color="violet" alt="Third Image">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/slide4.jpg" data-color="lightgreen" alt="Fourth Image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="carousel-captions">
    <div class="caption visible">
      <img src="images/banner2-text.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="caption second">
      <img src="images/banner3-text.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="caption third">
      <img src="images/banner4-text.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first caption is hiding properly with following jquery but how do I cycle through all the captions for each slides.

```
// Js
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $('.caption.visible').removeClass('visible');
})
```

Comment: I would say a more reliable / easier way to organize this would be to have the captions in the carousel `item` div. This way, you can just say something like `$(this).find('.caption').show()`. Otherwise, I would think in order to associate which caption goes to which slide you would need some data attribute for tracking

Comment: @Adjit nesting captions under the carousel item is not an option because of the full screen plugin I am using

Comment: Are you sure? I can't really see how it would effect your carousel if lets say you had a child div that is hidden and positionally set to absolute. Otherwise, look at jQuery's `.next()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** (just realized that you're actualy using bootstrap carousel)

Indicate which slide item is currently shown (by `:visible` or `.active` class), then grab its *index* and show `.caption` at the same *index*, using `.eq(index)`

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function(){
    var i = $('.item.active').index(); // or: $('.item:visible').index();
    $('.caption').removeClass('visible').eq(i).addClass('visible');
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/2o7g0042/)

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks.